# Calling function with callback defined as string

Tags: node.js, sails.js

```
var method = 'serviceName.MethodName'
```

I Just want to call it like

```
serviceName.methodName(function(output callback){

});
```

Is there any approach to call it.thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods that I can think of now.

1. JS eval
   You can use the javascript eval function to convert any string into code snippet like below. Although eval is a quick solution but should not be used unless you dont have any other option by your side.

   var method = 'UserService.getData';
   eval(method)();
2. Factory pattern
   Use a below pattern to get the service

You would need to define the services in such a manner that you can access them using a pattern.

```
var Services = {
// UserService and AccountsService are again objects having some callable functions.
    UserService : {getData: function(){}, getAge: function(){}},
    AccountsService : {getData: function(){}, getAge: function(){}},
// getService is the heart of the code which will get you the required service depending on the string paramter you pass.
    getService : function(serviceName){
        var service = '';
        switch(serviceName){
            case 'User':
                service = this.UserService;
                break;
            case 'Accounts':
                service = this.AccountsService;
                break;
        }
    return service;
}
}
```

You can use get the required service with below code

```
Services.getService('User')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way you can resolve the `serviceName` part of that string to an object, without using `eval`. So obviously you need to be extremely careful.

Perhaps:

```
if (method.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/) {
  var servicePart = eval(method.split('.')[0]);
  var methodPart = method.split('.')[1];
  servicePart[methodPart](...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate problems in your question:

1. How to access object property by property name (string)?
2. How to access object by it's name (string)?

Regarding the first problem - it is easy to access object property by string using the following notation:

```
const myObject = {
  myProp: 1,
};

console.log(myObject['myProp']);
```

And regarding the second problem - it depends on what `serviceName` is:

- if it is a property of some other object, then use `someObject['serviceName']['MethodName']`
- if it is a local variable, consider using a Map (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to associate strings with objects;